# Does this infinite isohedron with the surface topology of the gyroid have a name?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, minimal-surfaces

I was experimenting  with discretizations of the gyroid minimal surface in Rhino (3d modelling software), and modelled this infinite polyhedron, and wondered what it is called.
I didn't find any documentation of it yet, but perhaps I am not searching for the right terms.
**All its faces are the same isosceles triangle** (with angles of approx. 56.8°, 56.8°, 66.4°), and it has 2 types of vertices (with either 6 or 8 surrounding faces):

[image: Image of the polyhedron]

Applying Loop subdivision to this mesh gives a good approximation of the gyroid periodic minimal surface.

I found some other examples of infinite polyhedra with gyroid topology here:
https://theinnerframe.wordpress.com/2015/10/23/the-gyroids-algorithmic-geometry-iii/
but so far nothing with the same polyhedron as in my model.

Comment: Might as well put this here: https://twitter.com/alisonmartin57/status/1171087575106424834