# Book for Schwarz P and D surfaces

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, minimal-surfaces

Is there any english translation of the book "Gesammelte Mathematische Abhandlungen" by H. A. Schwarz? I am looking for book which has explained Schwarz P, Schwarz D triply periodic surface. Thank you!

Comment: Not a book but a good site (https://mathcurve.com/surfaces.gb/schwarz/schwarz.shtml#:~:text=The%20Schwarz%20%22D%22%20(for,a%20cube%2C%20as%20represented%20opposite)

Comment: Have a look at ["gyroids"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3589185/305862). See also "Encyclopedia of Analytical Surfaces" by Krivoshapko and Ivanov, Springer 2015 p. 433.

Comment: Thanks @JeanMarie . I am searching towards mathematical aspect of these surfaces like holomorphic, meromorphic forms, convergence of these surfaces with the change in their hyperelliptic equation etc.